# How to fix the scrollbar, so that it is being stretched from top to bottom?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I want to create a frame inside a canvas and I need to be able to scroll the contents of the frame.

I came to know that scrollbar cannot be added to the frame, so I am creating a canvas for that a scrollbar should be attached.But while creating scrollbar it is getting displayed smaller in a corner. I need a solution to fix it.
[Screenshot of my scroll bar problem](https://prnt.sc/mgqsn9)

```
root = Tk()
root.geometry("1000x1000")
root.title("Title")
root.grid_rowconfigure(2, weight=1)
root.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
canv=Canvas(root,width=600, height=600, background='blue')
vsb = Scrollbar(root, orient="vertical", command=canv.yview)
canv.config(yscrollcommand=vsb.set)
vsb.grid(row=0,column=1,sticky="ns")
canv.config(scrollregion=(0, 0,600,1000))
canv.grid(row=1, column=0)
canv.bind('<Configure>',canv.config(scrollregion=canv.bbox('all')))
```

So, I am expecting to have a label on top center (north) of my root screen and a scrollbar which should be able to scroll the contents of the entire screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you have `scrollbar` in `row=0`, and `canvas` in `row=1`. You have to make `canvas` and `scrollbar` in the same `row` but two different `columns`. Try this:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.geometry("1000x1000")
root.title("Title")

root.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
root.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
root.columnconfigure(1, weight=0)

canv = Canvas(root, width=600, height=600, background='blue')
vsb = Scrollbar(root, orient="vertical", command=canv.yview)
canv.config(yscrollcommand=vsb.set)
vsb.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky="ns")
canv.config(scrollregion=(0, 0, 600, 1000))
canv.grid(row=0, column=0)  # row = 0
canv.bind('<Configure>', canv.config(scrollregion=canv.bbox('all')))

root.mainloop()
```